# Unable to upload file (images) onto server in php using parse.com database

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am trying to upload file onto parse.com using PHP.
The code below works absolutely fine when I try upload the file(image) onto parse.com using "localhost"(Local Server). But when I connect to main server (Linux server) and try to upload the file(image) its not uploading into parse.
Please help me on this,
Thanks. Your help is most appreciated.

Here is the code below: (which is working fine in local server(localhost))

HTML code

```
 <table> 
    <tr>
    <td class="Lbl">Upload Picture:
     </td>
        <td>
         <input type="file" name="image">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

PHP code:

```
 if (isset( $_FILES['image'] ) && !empty($_FILES['image']) ) {

    if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 1000000)//approx. 1000kb files can be uploaded
    ){
    //PHP Image Uploading Code

      // save file to Parse
      $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
      $file->save();


    $test_file = new ParseObject("Picture");
    $test_file->set("Title", $pic_txt);
    $test_file->set("URL",$file);
    $test_file->save();

      // get the object ID
     $upload_object= $test_file->getObjectId();

  }}
```

Comment: thats not the issue, here is the updated code :)

Comment: The code is working great when I am working with the local server. but it is not working when I upload the file into linux server.

Comment: I copied the php file into my linux server and opened the file and when I select the image and try to save the file, It is not giving any error but it is not saving into my parse.com database. but the same file works absolutely fine when I work on my local machine using localhost server.

Comment: are you sure error_reporting is on for all errors and warnings? and yes have you tried putting the third arguement (i.e file type) in your `ParseFile::createFromData` function??

Comment: what is the third arguement that I can pass in ParseFile::createFromData function? can u please guide me

Comment: Anyone has any idea about this, please help me I am stuck with this issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, and the solution is :

In Linux server, provide RWX (Read, Write, Execute) permissions to the folder which you are working with.
and then execute the code, it will work perfectly

anyways, thanks for your time buddies.

To give RWX permission :

type :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <file name> or <file path>
```

eg:

```
chomod -R 777 var/www
```